# Call Python function from javascript inside client application

Tags: javascript, python

Is there any such library available which allow to run python code or any executable binary on the client machine using JavaScript. I have a strange scenario. All client machine use a web application hosted on a server, but authentication should be done using a device in the client machine using ttyUSB0 interface. Since it is not possible for a web application to access client machine, is it possible to create a client application using library like Pywebview which will allow to call that library directly from the web application using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not call a specific page of your web application (assuming your web application uses some web framework developed in python) via ajax with javascript and does this page execute a Python function (under the table)?

Comment: No, the web application runs on a different server and not on client machines. Ajax call will not work as the script need to be executed on client machine. Sorry for the confusion, I've edited my question.